# How can I bind to jQuery UI tab event click/select/active?

Tags: event-handling, bind, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm a beginner/intermediate level developer/programmer.  I've got jQuery-UI-Tabs that I'm building in jQuery like so (they show up and function fine):

```
   var paymentTabs = $('<div id="paytabs">');
...
var paymentTabList = $('<ul>');

paymentTabs.append(paymentTabList);
if($.inArray('check',options.methods) != -1){
paymentTabList.append('<li><a href="#pay-by-check">Pay with an E-Check</a></li>');
paymentTabs.append(payByCheck);
}
if($.inArray('card',options.methods) != -1){
paymentTabList.append('<li><a href="#pay-by-card">Pay with a Credit/Debit Card</a></li>');
paymentTabs.append(payByCard);
}
if($.inArray('code',options.methods) != -1){
paymentTabList.append('<li><a href="#pay-by-code">Business Office Use Only</a></li>');
paymentTabs.append(payByCode);
}

paymentTabs.tabs({show: function(event, ui) {
item.currentMethod = ui.panel.id;
self._refreshCart();
}
});

paymentTabs.tabs({show: function(event, ui) {
item.currentMethod = ui.panel.id;
self._refreshCart();
}
});
```

Binding to them does not work:

```
$( "#paytabs" ).on( "tabsselect", function(event, ui) {
alert("tab has been clicked.");
});
```

Neither does this:

```
$( "#paytabs" ).bind( "tabsselect", function(event, ui) {
alert("tab has been clicked.");
});
```

I also tried tabsactivate instead of tabsselect.  I tried selecting by class and by id.  I tried selecting transverse and walking the DOM.  Eventually, I'm going to use the function that I bind to the tab, to add a 3% fee to the billing total.  I will also make this function change the JSON key, attribute "required" to "true" for a specified input element.  This is critical for me to get this function bound... I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3):

Look here: http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-activate

Bind to the tab 'activate' event. So when a tab is clicked the activate function is fired.

Like This:

```
$("#paytabs").tabs({
   activate: function( event, ui ){
    /* do something here */
   }
 });
```

or

```
$("#paytabs").on( "tabsactivate", function( event, ui ){
    /* do something here */
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Neither syntax worked for me.  I'm using jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js  can I edit this file directly?  would that work?

Comment: Binding at the time of instanciating fires the event but kills the css.  `var paymentTabs = $('<div id="paytabs">').tabs({select: function( event, ui ) {alert("tab has been clicked.");}});;`

Comment: Google Element Inspector reveals that the DOM is being updated with the div class" '<div class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"><ul><li class=""><a href="#pay-by-check">Pay with an E-Check</a></li><li class=""><a href="#pay-by-card">Pay with a Credit/Debit Card</a></li></ul>'

Comment: And the li are rendered with a blank class.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what worked for me.  Aran's solution worked in part (thank you Aran).

Step One:
Bind to tabs activate as Aran described, but directly on the element as it is instantiated.  There is no need for an element selector if you do this.

```
billing_div.append('<h3>Payment Information</h3>');
  var paymentTabs = $('<div id="paytabs">').tabs({select: function( event, ui ) {alert("tab has been clicked.");}});
  billing_div.append(paymentTabs);
```

Step Two:
Add classes manually/problematically.  remember to include ui-tabs-selected only for the tab which tab is selected at page load.

```
var paymentTabList = $('<ul>').addClass('ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all');
      paymentTabs.append(paymentTabList);
      if($.inArray('check',options.methods) != -1){
        paymentTabList.append('<li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active"><a href="#pay-by-check">Pay with an E-Check</a></li>');
        paymentTabs.append(payByCheck);
      }
      if($.inArray('card',options.methods) != -1){
        paymentTabList.append('<li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><a href="#pay-by-card">Pay with a Credit/Debit Card</a></li>');
        paymentTabs.append(payByCard);
      }
      if($.inArray('code',options.methods) != -1){
        paymentTabList.append('<li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><a href="#pay-by-code">Business Office Use Only</a></li>');
        paymentTabs.append(payByCode);
      }
```